# Hilbert transform of symbolic function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fourier, hilbert-transform

I have a signal of the form $f(\omega,x) = g(\omega) e^{i \omega (x +c)},$ for $g: [\omega_1 , \omega_2] \rightarrow C, \, x\in R$ and some constant $c.$  I want to get the function
$$
F (\omega,x) = \mathcal{H} ( \Re \{f(\cdot,x)\}) (\omega),
$$
where $\mathcal{H}$ denotes the Hilbert transform with respect to frequency $\omega,$ and $\Re$ the real part. I need the function $F$ to be again symbolic on $x$ such that I can differentiate it later.

I am trying to implement it in Matlab using:

```
L = 1e-2; K = 100; c = 1;
omega = (1/L)*(-K:K-1);

g = exp(-omega.^2/4);

syms x; f(x) = real(g.*exp(1i*omega*(x+c)));
```

but then the hilbert build-in function is not working. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The real part, the Hilbert transform and the derivation are all operators that commute.  So you can move the derivative just close to the function.

Comment: "commune"?  or "commute"?

Comment: I don't even have the excuse that letters are close on the keyboard

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I think this does answer my question. The derivative is with respect to x and the Hilbert with respect to omega. My question is if the hilbert transform can be applied to f, that is symbolic at x, and result to a symbolic function at x.